# Show / Hide class function for <a> link showing table content

Tags: jquery, class, html-table, show-hide

I'm struggling with show/hide option using classes for the content I placed inside the table. I'm a beginner in JQuery and only little more advanced in html but would love to have that working properly. I would like to have sth like this:

Link: *See more...* placed in one row of the table

- when clicked, it shows the whole table with more description placed withing current table with link and then link content changes to Hide;
- when clicked again it hides this table with more description and link content changes again to See more

I did it on two different links, in two different places but I would like to do it on one.

This is what I have in html for the link Show

```
<a class="show" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: blue">object 1 </a>
```

This is what I have for a part of a table that should be shown after clicking the link:

```
<tr style="display: none" class="desc">
  <td colspan="2">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="10" summary="Object 1">
      (description)
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is what I have for the link Hide:

```
<td style="padding:5px" colspan="2" align="center"><a class="hide" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: blue">Hide the description...</a></td>
```

And JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#hotels .show').click(function () {
    $('#hotels tr.desc').hide();
    var tr = $(this).parentsUntil('tr').last().parent();
    tr.next().show();
  });

  $('#hotels .hide').click(function () {
    var tr = $(this).parentsUntil('table').last().parentsUntil('tr').last().parent();
    tr.hide();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try with following code:

**Note:** Can't test it as don't have specific HTML for this:

HTML Code:

```
<a class="showhide" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: blue">See more...</a>
```

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#hotels .showhide').click(function () {
    if($(this).text() == "See more...")
    {
        //show the contents
        $('#hotels tr.desc').hide();
        var tr = $(this).parentsUntil('tr').last().parent();
        tr.next().show();
        $(this).text("Hide");
    }
    else
    {
        //hide the contents
        $('#hotels tr.desc').hide();
        $(this).text("See more...");
    }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help and solutions. Maybe sending whole html would be better idea. The solution given by @vijayP was so far the closest to perfect because was working with specific "See more" text. But I think I will make it from here by myself.

Comment: thats great @TomaszKoralewski...! +1 for this.

Comment: I gotta reach a specific level to make my +1 public :(

Comment: yes...thats true @TomaszKoralewski. I think you need at least 15 reputation to upvote others post. Keep posting good stuff and within no time you will be there... `:)`!

Comment: do you have any idea why this solution does not work on Firefox and IE (EDGE) browsers? It works well on Chrome&Opera. Is JQuery having some problems with those browsers?

Answer (score 1):

I could do something reusable and in a different, more organized way. Consider this snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".see-more").click(function () {
    $($(this).attr("href")).toggleClass("show");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.see-more-target .see-show {display: none;}
.see-more-target.show .see-show {display: inline;}
.see-more-target.show .see-hide {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<a href="#see-more-1" class="see-more">See More 1</a>

<div id="see-more-1" class="see-more-target">
  <p>This is the content of see more 1. <span class="see-hide"><a href="#see-more-1" class="see-more">See More</a></span><span class="see-show"><a href="#see-more-1" class="see-more">Hide It</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem optio dolorum sed qui mollitia aperiam nulla voluptate veritatis vel error eius consequatur quae quisquam, ut doloremque odio repellat iste id.</span></p>
</div>

<a href="#see-more-2" class="see-more">See More 2</a>

<div id="see-more-2" class="see-more-target">
  <p>This is the content of see more 1. <span class="see-hide">More...</span><span class="see-show">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem optio dolorum sed qui mollitia aperiam nulla voluptate veritatis vel error eius consequatur quae quisquam, ut doloremque odio repellat iste id.</span></p>
</div>
```

Okay, may be you are asking something like this?

```js
$(function () {
  $('[href="#show"]').click(function () {
    $(this).closest("p").addClass("open");
    return false;
  });
  $('[href="#hide"]').click(function () {
    $(this).closest("p").removeClass("open");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
p.open a.show,
p span.more {display: none;}
p.open span.more {display: inline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<p>Microsoft Corporation /ˈmaɪkrɵsɒft, -sɔːft/ (commonly referred to as Microsoft) is an American multinational technology company headquartered in Redmond, Washington, that develops <a href="#show" class="show">Show</a><span class="more">, manufactures, licenses, supports and sells computer software, consumer electronics and personal computers and services. Its best known software products are the Microsoft Windows line of operating systems, Microsoft Office office suite, and Internet Explorer and Edge web browsers. Its flagship hardware products are the Xbox game consoles and the Microsoft Surface tablet lineup. It is the world's largest software maker by revenue, and one of the world's most valuable companies. <a href="#hide">Hide</a></span></p>
<p>Microsoft was founded by Paul Allen and Bill Gates on April 4, 1975, to develop and sell BASIC interpreters for Altair 8800. <a href="#show" class="show">Show</a><span class="more">It rose to dominate the personal computer operating system market with MS-DOS in the mid-1980s, followed by Microsoft Windows. The company's 1986 initial public offering, and subsequent rise in its share price, created three billionaires and an estimated 12,000 millionaires among Microsoft employees. Since the 1990s, it has increasingly diversified from the operating system market and has made a number of corporate acquisitions. In May 2011, Microsoft acquired Skype Technologies for $8.5 billion in its largest acquisition to date. <a href="#hide">Hide</a></span></p>
<p>As of 2015, Microsoft is market dominant in both the IBM PC-compatible operating system (while it lost the majority of the overall operating system market to Android) and office software suite markets (the latter with Microsoft Office). <a href="#show" class="show">Show</a><span class="more">The company also produces a wide range of other software for desktops and servers, and is active in areas including Internet search (with Bing), the video game industry (with the Xbox, Xbox 360 and Xbox One consoles), the digital services market (through MSN), and mobile phones (via the operating systems of Nokia's former phones and Windows Phone OS). In June 2012, Microsoft entered the personal computer production market for the first time, with the launch of the Microsoft Surface, a line of tablet computers. <a href="#hide">Hide</a></span></p>
```

Comment: True, but the problem is that `id`s become unwieldy, they don't scale well.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The OP wants it to be accessible from anywhere, so proposed this kind of generic approach. `:)`

Comment: @Praveen This is not exactly what I'm trying to achieve. After clicking "See more 1" there should be a totally additional content shown and user should see that he can hide it quickly by clicking "hide"

Comment: @TomaszKoralewski When you click on the link, it shows some contents. Okay, I can make `Show / Hide` links too. Just add it to the HTML.

Comment: @TomaszKoralewski Kindly look at the updated snippet in the answer for the first demo.

Comment: @TomaszKoralewski Kindly check the updated 2nd snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the show/hide link is in its own row, as that seems to be what you're describing:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <a class="show" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: blue">object 1 </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

If so, and if the description row always follows it, you can just use `closest("tr")`, `next`, and `toggle`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".show", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
  return false;
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".show", function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <a class="show" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: blue">object 1 </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none" class="desc">
      <td colspan="2">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="10" summary="Object 1">
          (Description 1)
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <a class="show" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: blue">object 2</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none" class="desc">
      <td colspan="2">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="10" summary="Object 2">
          (Description 2)
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <a class="show" href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: blue">object 3 </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: none" class="desc">
      <td colspan="2">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="10" summary="Object 3">
          (Description 3)
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That said, though, it starts getting unnecessarily complicated and hard to maintain when you want to do something like toggle the text of the link as well. Instead, I'd put the description table **inside** the `td` with the link, toggle a class on the `td`, and use CSS to manage what gets shown/hidden and how:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".toggle", function() {
  $(this).closest(".toggleable").toggleClass("showing");
  return false;
});
```

```css
.toggleable .desc {
  display: none;
}
.toggleable.showing .desc {
  display: block;
}
.toggleable .show,
.toggleable .hide {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
.toggleable .hide {
  display: none;
}
.toggleable.showing .hide {
  display: inline;
}
.toggleable.showing .show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="toggleable" colspan="2">
        <a class="toggle show" href="#">object 1</a>
        <a class="toggle hide" href="#">hide details</a>
        <table class="desc" border="0" cellspacing="10" summary="Object 1">
          <tr>
            <td>
              (Description 1)
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="toggleable" colspan="2">
        <a class="toggle show" href="#">object 2</a>
        <a class="toggle hide" href="#">hide details</a>
        <table class="desc" border="0" cellspacing="10" summary="Object 2">
          <tr>
            <td>
              (Description 2)
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="toggleable" colspan="2">
        <a class="toggle show" href="#">object 3</a>
        <a class="toggle hide" href="#">hide details</a>
        <table class="desc" border="0" cellspacing="10" summary="Object 3">
          <tr>
            <td>
              (Description 3)
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note the class on the `td` that contains everything (`toggleable`), and the classes on the various players (`show`, `hide`, `toggle`) and how the CSS is in charge of what happens.

Comment: Hey @T.J. Crowder - this one works too. Thank you very much.